# One person not traveling first leg of the journey

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations

I bought a roundtrip ticket between two US cities A->B->A for two people. One of us will not do the flight A->B. From what I've seen in other questions, I don't expect this person to be able to do B->A.

- Can the other person do A->B?
- Can the other person do B->A?
- Can I do something to solve this mess that doesn't involve paying lots of money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've read is correct. Rules may vary based on the particular airline's Contract of Carriage, but in general:

- Yes. If only one of you shows up for A->B that shouldn't be a problem.
- Probably. Once the other person doesn't show up for A->B their return ticket will be cancelled, however, even if booked together the two tickets should have different ticket numbers. Hence, I would expect that the ticket of the person who did fly A->B will still be honored. However, I would strongly encourage you to contact the airline to confirm.
- Probably not. Unless you or the other person has status with the airline on which you are flying, in which case if you call the elite help desk, get a particularly nice agent, and really sell your reasoning for dropping A->B they *may* have mercy on you. However, most likely not.